# How can I change the images size on PageViewController in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8, uipageviewcontroller

[image]

When I first faced this problem on other `ViewController`, I solved it by setting constraint constants.

[image]

But, on the `PageViewController`, I cannot solve this problem.

These are codes about `PageViewController`.
I have 2 swift files related to `PageViewController` and there is only one `ViewController` on `Main.storyboard` to show page-based screen and it's linked to FirstPageViewController.swift

*FirstPageViewController.swift*

```
import UIKit

class FirstPageViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

    var pageViewController : UIPageViewController?
    var pageTitles : Array<String> = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
        // pageTitles 배열의 수를 기준으로 페이지가 생성 되므로 원하는 페이지만큼 ""를 입력해야 함.
    var pageImages : Array<String> = ["S1_01.jpg", "S1_02.jpg", "S1_03.jpg", "S1_04.jpg", "S1_05.jpg", "S1_06.jpg", "S1_07.jpg", "S1_08.jpg", "S1_09.jpg", "S1_10.jpg", "S1_11.jpg", "S1_12.jpg"] // 그림자극장 page에 들어갈 이미지 파일들
    var currentIndex : Int = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        showSecondAlert()
        showFirstAlert()

        pageViewController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .pageCurl, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: nil)
        pageViewController!.dataSource = self // (transitionStyle: 페이지 넘김 형식, navigationOrientation: 페이지 방향, options: nil)

        let startingViewController: FirstDataViewController = viewControllerAtIndex(index: 0)!
        let viewControllers = [startingViewController]

        pageViewController!.setViewControllers(viewControllers , direction: .forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
        pageViewController!.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height);

        addChildViewController(pageViewController!)
        view.addSubview(pageViewController!.view)

        pageViewController!.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        var index = (viewController as! FirstDataViewController).pageIndex

        if (index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound) {
            return nil
        }

        index -= 1

        return viewControllerAtIndex(index: index)
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        var index = (viewController as! FirstDataViewController).pageIndex

        if index == NSNotFound {
            return nil
        }

        index += 1

        if (index == self.pageTitles.count) {
            return nil
        }

        return viewControllerAtIndex(index: index)
    }

    func viewControllerAtIndex(index: Int) -> FirstDataViewController? {
        if self.pageTitles.count == 0 || index >= self.pageTitles.count {
            return nil
        }

        let pageContentViewController = FirstDataViewController()
        pageContentViewController.imageFile = pageImages[index]
        pageContentViewController.titleText = pageTitles[index]
        pageContentViewController.pageIndex = index
        currentIndex = index

        return pageContentViewController
    }

    func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return self.pageTitles.count
    }

    func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return 0
    }

    func showFirstAlert() { // 그림자 극장 실행 전 플래쉬를 켜달라는 알림 팝업창
        let sendAlert = UIAlertView(title: "잠시만요!", message: "그림자극장을 실행하기 전에 플래쉬를 작동해주세요.", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
        sendAlert.show()
    }

    func showSecondAlert() { // 그림자 극장 실행 전 플래쉬를 켜달라는 알림 팝업창
        let sendAlert = UIAlertView(title: "", message: "책장을 넘기듯이 페이지를 넘겨주세요. 메뉴로 돌아가시려면 화면 상단을 터치하세요.", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
        sendAlert.show()
    }
}
```

*FirstDataViewController.swift*

```
import UIKit

class FirstDataViewController: UIViewController {

    var pageIndex : Int = 0
    var titleText : String = ""
    var imageFile : String = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: imageFile)!)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: The size of all images is 375 x 667 pixel and I want to set them on the PageViewController .
It's fit on iPhone 6/6s/7 simulator, but it's not on other ios devices.

Comment: I deleted some words cuz they thought it looked like spam...

Comment: Non-Latin characters are detected as spam. This shouldn't be a big problem, as this is an English-only website. In the future, please translate your comments from Korean to English. That will both bypass the spam filter *and* ensure that everyone can read them.

Comment: Oh, thank you. But, I didn't use any Non-Latin characters... They said "I want to, I'm using, etc." look like spam.

Comment: The messages basically lie to you, in hopes of not giving away our secrets to actual spammers. This has become unfortunately necessary because we have recently gotten *a lot* of spam in CJK characters. The comment in your code (within the variable declaration) appears to be written in Hangul characters (I think? Not entirely sure.). Either way, these are definitely non-Latin, and are probably enough to trigger the block. Sorry that you were tripped up—you are obviously not a spammer.

Comment: Why you have to set image as background color o_O? Why not just use `UIImageView` for images? Is there any problem using `UIImageView`?